# Trying multiplying numbers on a line starting with the word "size" with a constant variable across 181 text files

Tags: python, notepad++, emeditor

I have a folder of 181 text file, each containing numbers but I only need to multiply those on lines that have "size" by a constant variable such as 0.5, but I did achieve this with this: [Search and replace math operations with the result in Notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/968315/search-and-replace-math-operations-with-the-result-in-notepad?rq=1)
But what I am trying to do is without expression or quotation marks so that the rest of the community I am in can simply do the same without editing every file to meet the format needed to multiply each number.
For Example:

```
    farmers = {
        culture = armenian
        religion = coptic
        size = 11850
    }
```

being multiplied by 0.5 to:

```
    farmers = {
        culture = armenian
        religion = coptic
        size = 5925
    }
```

I tried making a python script but it did not work although I don't know much python:

```
import operator

with open('*.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()

factor = 0.5
count = 0

for index, line in enumerate(data):
    try:
        first_word = line.split()[0]
    except IndexError:
        pass

    if first_word == 'size':
        split_line = line.split(' ')
        # print(' '.join(split_line))
        # print(split_line)
        new_line = split_line

        new_line[-1] = ("{0:.6f}".format(float(split_line[-1]) * factor))
        new_line = ' '.join(new_line) + '\n'
        # print(new_line)

        data[index] = new_line

        count += 1

    elif first_word == 'text_scale':
        split_line = line.split(' ')
        # print(split_line)
        # print(' '.join(split_line))
        new_line = split_line

        new_line[-1] = "{0:.2f}".format(float(split_line[-1]) * factor)
        new_line = ' '.join(new_line) + '\n'
        # print(new_line)

        data[index] = new_line

        count += 1


with open('*.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(data)

print("Lines changed:", count)
```

So are there any solutions to this, I rather not make people in my community format every single file to work with my solution. Anything could work just that I haven't found a simple solution that is quick and easy for anyone to understand for those who use notepad++ or Sublime Text 3.

Comment: I can answer to this question if it is OK with using EmEditor.

Comment: I am okay with using EmEditor.

Comment: I answered to your question using EmEditor. Please add the `emeditor` tag to your question.

Comment: How consistent will your team be with formatting? Do you want to keep their file identically, except for the size part? Or will they provide structured text like the above?

Comment: Practically it must be size = X without any extra symbols or words

Answer (score 0):

If you use **EmEditor**, you can use the **Replace in Files** feature of EmEditor. In EmEditor, select **Replace in Files** on the **Search** menu (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>), and enter:

**Find**: `(?<=\s)size(.*?)(\d+)`

**Replace with**: `\J "size\1" + \2 / 2`

**File Types**: `*.txt` (or file extension you are looking for)

**In Folder**: (folder path you are searching in)

Set the **Keep Modified Files Open** and **Regular Expressions** options (and **Match Case** option if `size` always appears in lower case),

Click the **Replace All** button.

[image: EmEditor - Replace in Files dialog box]

Alternatively, if you would like to use a macro, this is a macro for you (you need to edit the folder path):

```
editor.ReplaceInFiles("(?<=\\s)size(.*?)(\\d+)","\\J \x22size\\1\x22 + \\2 / 2","E:\\Test\\*.txt",eeFindReplaceCase | eeFindReplaceRegExp | eeReplaceKeepOpen,0,"","",0,0);
```

To run this, save this code as, for instance, `Replace.jsee`, and then select this file from **Select...** in the **Macros** menu. Finally, select **Run Replace.jsee** in the **Macros** menu.

**Explanations:**

`\J` in the replacement expression specifies JavaScript. In this example, `\2` is the backreference from `(\d+)`, thus `\2 / 2` represents a matched number divided by two.

**References:** [EmEditor How to: Replace Expression Syntax](http://www.emeditor.org/en/howto_search_replacement_expression_syntax.html)

Comment: If I wanted to multiply rather divide would it use  \J "size\1" + * 2  if I am wrong, sorry I am not used to regex.

Comment: It would be `\J "size\1" + \2 * 2` if you want to multiply.