# Multiply numbers in mass replace

Tags: python, notepad++

I'm using notepad++ to edit a YAML file, and since NPP can't replace numbers using arithmetic I thought that maybe a python script would do the job (Using PythonScript plugin in NPP). Problem is, I'm very bad at python and I can't get it to work. What I want to do is multiply all numbers following "income:" by 10:

```
income: 0.5
points: 0.15
experience: 0.3
```

I've tried to run this script:

```
def multiply_number_in_context(match):
    return "{0}{1}{2}".format(match.group(1), str(float(match.group(2))*10), '"')

editor.rereplace(r'(income: )(\d+)', multiply_number_in_context)
```

But it returns the following:

```
        income: 0.0".5
        points: 0.15
        experience: 0.3
```

Any help with this? Thanks!

Comment: `\d` only matches digits, so your match did not include the decimal point and final 5.  Use something like `([0-9.]+)` for that second capturing group.

Comment: I don't quite understand the purpose of the second paragraph. To me, that looks like more than a simple arithmetic command. The solution should be easy and max. 10 lines of code

Comment: This is similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64560449/trying-multiplying-numbers-on-a-line-starting-with-the-word-size-with-a-consta

Answer (score 0):

The python solution for the arithmetic operation should look like this:

```
#Define your current list
income = [0.5, ...]

#Define your goal
income = [i * 10 for i in income]

#Print the results
print(income)
```

Comment: OP asked for *PythonScript*, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

This works. Tested with NPP v7.8.7 64bit.

```
import re

pattern = r"(?<=income: )([^\n]*)"

def func(match):
    return 10 * float(match.group(1))

editor.rereplace(pattern, func)
```

Use *Positive lookahead* to match preceding token, while not including in result.

This way you're only matching token behind it, eliminating need to replace entire line.